# Create a new sheet for each row

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel sheet, I have roughly 30 rows x 100 columns of data. Each row represents a different "client". For each client, I've create a summary sheet that is emailed to them and that also contains all the information from my main sheet

Is there a way for Excel to create a new sheet based on some template sheet when I add a new row to my main sheet and fill it with the appropriate data?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that with "regular" methods. A way to do that would be only with VBA (like you already described in tag), and in this case, your question will probably have better answers on StackOverflow, as it is rather programming related. I'm voting to migrate your question there (but that's only my opinion, anyone can disagree).

Comment: Do you have any experience with macros/VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this to happen *automatically* on the addition of a row then you would need to use the `Worksheet_Change` event to capture the completion of a new row.

This would then generate a new workbook from the template, copy across the necessary ranges then save the new file somewhere, much as Gnoupi says

All this is relatively trivial with VBA, but unfortunately if you aren't familiar with VBA then isn't a simple case of "Do X then do Y in Excel" so I think you may struggle, even with sample code posted here.

Even if I created a dummy model that did what you require, functionally at least, then customising it to your particular needs may difficult if you are not used to working with Excel programmatically.

**Edit**
I've created a *very* simple demonstration of how this could work:  http://drop.io/4clxof3 - note this example doesn't include the event handling for adding a new row, has almost no validation or error handling and makes sweeping assumptions about almost everything(!)

If you feel comfortable using this a basis for developing your own solution then great.  If the whole VBA thing is foreign to you then it may be time to call in reinforcements :)

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't know about the "Worksheet_change" event, good to know.

Answer (score 3):

I will give you my opinion about your need, the way I see it, at least. It is not a "ready to use" solution, however, only some ideas about the way to do that.

---

<strike>From what I know, there is no way to track insertion of a row in Excel. So you would require a VBA function to be activated on a button, for example.</strike> *Actually, there is, see Lunatik's answer.*

This function would loop over all rows in your main sheet, and create a new sheet when necessary (you would need preferably a unique id for each client, it could be a simple index on the main sheet, depending on the line).

You would create at first your template sheet, with a specific name, and eventually hide it (to not have it in the visible tabs). When I say that the function would create, it would in fact copy this template sheet and give it a unique name (the id I mentioned earlier). You can find ways to copy sheets at [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288402).

A second operation to do, would be to put data from the row in the main sheet, to the template sheet (if I understood correctly your requirement), which is not really complicated to do in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

i was wondering if it was possible with no error catching. Simply just have a VBA code that takes each row of the Excel Document - Creates a file for each row and then at the end combines the total files in a folder into one?

I know sounds weird.. but is this possible?